# NAV Web Services getting data in chunks using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I am a bit new to NAV and so far I have published web services on NAV and have been able to consume these SOAP web services using C#.

Now, the data has increased and its taking longer to load. I have an idea of querying the data in chunks (e.g chunks of 10) using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/), but this I am yet too figure out how to set limits and offsets.

Here is my C# code to read the NAV soap service

```
public string getItemCardList(itemCardService_Service itemCardServiceObj, List<itemCardService_Filter> filter)
{
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = 50000000;
    return serializer.Serialize(itemCardServiceObj.ReadMultiple(filter.ToArray(), null, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some several searches I have gotten the answer on the [MSDN Website][https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477110.aspx] and modified it to work for me.

```
public string holder()
        {
           const int fetchSize = 10;
           string bookmarkKey = null;

            List<itemCardService> itemList = new List<itemCardService>();
            //Read items data in pages of 10
            itemCardService[] results = itemCardServiceObj.ReadMultiple(filter.ToArray(), bookmarkKey, fetchSize);
            while(results.Length > 0)
            {
                bookmarkKey = results.Last().Key;
                itemList.AddRange(results);
                results = itemCardServiceObj.ReadMultiple(filter.ToArray(), bookmarkKey, fetchSize);
            }
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = 50000000;
            return serializer.Serialize(itemList);
        }
```